# Why is crontab running my script If I have no cron jobs configured?

Tags: macos, cron

I don't know why, but every 5 minutes I am receiving a report mail from a php script that I used to run with a sh script using crontab, but I removed all cron jobs with `crontab -r` but the script is still being run even when `crontab -l` returns: `crontab: no crontab for administrator`

How can I stop crontab or how can I find the configuration that runs the sh script every 5 minutes?

Comment: Do you have a system-wide crontab (generally /etc/crontab or something in /etc/cron.d, or something similar).

Comment: Hello, Reviewed the issue and I had to remove manually as root user the crontab folder.